# How to replace /dev/urandom with rand()?

Tags: c, random

On ubuntu the program uses

```
FILE *randomSource = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");
int byteCount = fread(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), num, randomSource);
```

And I would like to replace this with rand() from stdlib because I need to use it in an environment where there is no /dev/urandom.
I've tried this way:

```
buf = malloc (num);
int i;

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
  buf[i] = rand ();
}
```

But apparently it is not equivalent because the program fails. The result should be n random bytes with buf pointing to the first.

I tried it like this too, still fails.

```
randomBytes(unsigned char *buf, const int num)
{
    buf = malloc (num * sizeof *buf);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
      buf[i] = rand ();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The original function I am trying to replace is:

```
randomBytes(unsigned char *buf, const int num)
{
    FILE *randomSource = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");

    if (!randomSource)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int byteCount = fread(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), num, randomSource);

    if (byteCount < num)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(randomSource);

    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of it is just to test an idea not a cryptographic application.

Comment: Please provide some [MRE] in your question.

Comment: `buf = malloc(num * sizeof *buf);`

Comment: @wildplasser: `buf`  is probably declared as `char*buf;`  and then `sizeof *buf`  is 1

Comment: I know that, but buff was not declared anywhere, and it wont harm.

Comment: If you're using /dev/urandom then almost certainly you're using it for security purposes. You can't replace it with `rand()` without sacrificing *all* the security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain how does the program fails. Read more about [rand](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random) and consider seeding your [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). You might be interested by the [Mersenne twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister): on some platforms it is a much better PRNG that `rand`. Without seeding `rand` has a *reproducible* behavior.

Also [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) can fail, and you don't test against that. If `malloc` fails, `buf` is `NULL`, and the first loop of your `for` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): you dereferences the `NULL` pointer (probably a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)).

Suggested reading: [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Consider compiling your code on Ubuntu with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You might get useful warnings.

Consider using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) on Ubuntu.

> I tried this

```
randomBytes(unsigned char *buf, const int num)
{
    buf = malloc (num * sizeof *buf);
    int i;
```

You are *overwriting* the `buf` passed in argument. Better yet not even pass it (and perhaps return such a buffer).

Please read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), then some good [C programming](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site, the documentation of your debugger (on Ubuntu, of [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)), the documentation of your compiler (on Ubuntu, of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/)) then the C11 standard ([n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

Comment: It does encryption and even on Ubuntu if I switch the two then the encryption fails that is why I think the two don't equivalently give back n random bytes.

Comment: Wow thank you very much!!! I don't understand why it didn't work with overwriting. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `malloc` anything in the function `randomBytes()`.  The parameter `buf` already points to a buffer sufficient to hold `num` bytes.  All you have to do is fill it.

```
randomBytes(unsigned char *buf, const int num)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
      buf[i] = rand ();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you did `buf = malloc()`, you overwrote your parameter `buf` with a pointer to a new block of memory, and wrote the random bytes in the new block.  The original block, which the caller expected to have filled by random bytes, was therefore not touched.  Moreover, the new block you allocated is never freed, and after `randomBytes` returns, you no longer have any pointers to it, so it is leaked.  (Remember that C functions pass arguments by value, so assigning to the parameter `buf` itself has no effect on any variables in any other functions - though assigning to `buf[i]` is a different story.) So all around, that is not what you want to do.

This could be made a bit more efficient, since `rand()` returns a random value between 0 and `RAND_MAX` which is usually something like 31 bits of randomness, so you could fill more than one byte per call to `rand()`.  But it should certainly suffice to get started.

Don't forget to call `srand()` somewhere in your program if you don't want to get the same sequence of random bytes on every run.

Finally, keep in mind that on many systems `rand()` is a rather low quality random number generator.  In particular, it absolutely must not be used for any cryptographic purposes, or for games of chance where there is money at stake.